Small doubt concerning $\mathsf{ZF}$ model construction
I know the following must be wrong, but I'm feeling a tad confused as to where exactly it goes wrong: Consider the theory $\mathrm{Th}(\mathsf{ZF})$ in the language $\mathcal{L}_{\mathsf{ZF}}$. Now consider some structure $\mathcal{M} = \langle M, \in_M\rangle$ with $M = \{m\}$ for some $m$ and $\in_M = \emptyset$. We want $\mathcal{M}$ to verify Extensionality (which at this stage it trivially does), hence we quotient $M$ by $\sim$ with $m \sim n$ if $\mathcal{M} \models \forall x \ (x \in \overline{m} \leftrightarrow x \in \overline{n})$ and consider $\mathcal{M}/\sim = \langle M/\sim, \in_{M/\sim}\rangle$ (whenever $(m, n) \in \in_M$, $([m]_\sim, [n]_\sim) \in \in_{M/\sim}$).
Now, we want $\mathcal{M}/\sim$ to also verify the remaining axioms (Separation, Union, Pairs, etc.), so, in the case of Union for example, for every $m \in \mathcal{M}/\sim$, we shall introduce a new element $c_m$ into $\mathcal{M}/\sim$ together with the pairs $(n, c_m)$ whenever $\mathcal{M}/\sim \models \exists x \in \overline{m} \ (\overline{n} \in x)$. As for Separation, we shall grab each $m \in \mathcal{M}/\sim$ and, for each $\phi(x) \in \mathcal{L}_{\mathsf{ZF}}$, add a new element $c_{(m,\phi)}$ together with the pairs $(n, c_{(m,\phi)})$ whenever $\mathcal{M}/\sim \models \overline{n} \in \overline{m} \land \phi(\overline{n})$. I realize that the addition of a new element to verify Infinity at this stage might prove problematic so consider instead that we commence with $M = \omega+1$ (i.e. $\{0, 1, \dots, \omega\}$).
Once we have performed these sort of procedures for every axiom of $\mathsf{ZF}$, we once again quotient by Extensionality and yet again perform the procedures on the resulting set. Doing so yields a sequence $(\mathcal{M}/\sim)_0, (\mathcal{M}/\sim)_1, \dots$ of structures. My question is: would $(\bigcup(\mathcal{M}/\sim)_n)/\sim$ not work as a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$?

Why should, for example, Separation hold at the end of the construction? Maybe an element $a$ satisfies a property $\varphi$ in each $\mathcal{M}_i$ but not in the union. This is based on an idea which works (Skolem functions), but there's a lot of crucial details being skipped over here.

@NoahSchweber Thank you for the response. You are right that it is not immediate why Separation might hold at the union of all $\mathcal{M}_i$. I could be wrong but, it seems (sort of) intuitive that it might, still, given how one's constructing from the "bottom up" and any problematic formula who suddenly had a change in truth-value might just have been replicated by some other formula at a previous stage. Nevertheless, you raise a good objection!

@NoahSchweber (I noticed also that there's nothing really even guaranteeing that Ext may hold, as the resulting $\mathcal{M}_i$ at each stage need not be in accord uniformly with each other wrt the equiv. classes involved therein; and a final, all-encompassing Ext quotient to the whole union is by itself insufficient insofar as one would need basically infinitely many such quotients in the case that one had two extensionally equivalent but distinct sets, their singletons, the singletons thereof, etc., so that when one identified the first, the latter would now have to be identified, and so on.

@NoahSchweber You mention however that this is based on certain ideas which work (Skolem functions). I think when I posited it I was initially thinking about the way one constructs a Henkin theory? Nevertheless, do you think then that there's some way to make this whole thing "work" (perhaps with a bit of alteration as to its resulting capabilities)?
